# Showing integral on contour tends to zero

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, power-series, contour-integration

I'm trying to prove:

$$\int \frac{e^{t(z+\frac{1}{z})}}{z^2} = \sum_0 ^{\infty} b_m t^{2m+1}$$

Where the integral is over a contour centre the origin, radius R, and the $b_m$ are some coefficients.

Now I can obtain these coefficients by considering the resiude at $z=0$ and multiplying the power series for $e^{tz}$ and $e^{t/z}$ however I am now having difficulty in showing that as $R \to \infty$ the integral around the contour tends to zero, any hints on this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: The integral is independent of $R$.

Comment: I can't see how the integral is independent of $R$, I am integrating the function over a circle of radius $R$?

Comment: But there's only one singularity (in $\mathbb{C}$), the essential singularity in $0$, so the integral depends only on the winding number of the contour around $0$. That is independent of $R$.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure I've come across that before. Usually I would try and find some bound when $|z| = R$ on $f(z)$

Comment: Oh no, I am being really stupid, I see exactly what you are saying now, as in we only need to do that method when, say for example considering a semi-circle contour and we want to show the top half goes to zero, leaving us with, say, an integral on the real line. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ R}{\exp\pars{t\bracks{z + 1/z}} \over z^2}\,\dd z:\
     {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ R}
> {\exp\pars{t\bracks{z + 1/z}} \over z^2}\,\dd z}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ R}{\exp\pars{tz}\exp\pars{t/z} \over z^2}\,\dd z
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ R}{1 \over z^2}\,
> \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{t^{m}z^{m} \over m!}
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{t^{n}z^{-n} \over n!}\,\dd z
> =\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{t^{m + n} \over m!\,n!}\
> \overbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ R}{\dd z \over z^{2 - m + n}}}
> ^{\ds{=\ 2\pi\ic\,\delta_{m,n + 1}}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\pi\ic\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{t^{2n + 1} \over \pars{n + 1}!\,n!}
> =\color{#66f}{\large 2\pi\ic\ {\rm I}_{1}\pars{2t}}
> \end{align}

where $\ds{{\rm I}_{\alpha}\pars{x}}$ is the
[Modified Bessel Function of the First Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_%3a_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1).